# Django - Celery Worker won't start; finds multiple errors in apps

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

So I've been working on Django project for some months now, and a while back I set up a test installation of Celery which worked fine. Since that time, I've done a few things, upgraded my third-party apps and Django itself to 1.9. Today I wanted to implement celery again and couldn't get it to start. It's throwing multiple errors in my apps that Django itself isn't complaining about. It's also ignoring apps that I've overriden.

My file structure

```
src/
   apps/
      core/
         settings/
             production.py
             development.py
         __init__.py
         apps.py
         celery.py
         wsgi.py
         ...
      app1/
      app2/
      ...
      manage.py
```

My celery.py

```
from celery import Celery
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'core.settings.development')

from django.conf import settings

app = Celery('core')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

Using this command:

```
celery --app=core worker --loglevel=INFO
```

I'm getting things like:

```
File "/Users/../src/apps/core/urls.py", line 17, in <module>
     from users.views import *
File "/Users/../src/apps/users/views.py", line 21, in <module>
  from allauth.account.views import SignupView as AllAuthSignupView
File "/Users/../site/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 19, in <module>
from .forms import (
File "/Users/../site/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/account/forms.py", line 206, in <module>
class BaseSignupForm(_base_signup_form_class()):
File "/Users/../site/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/account/forms.py", line 188, in _base_signup_form_class
' "%s"' % (fc_module, e))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing form class core.forms: "cannot import name generic"
```

and

```
File "/Users/../site/lib/python2.7/site-packages/review/models.py", line 3, in <module>
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
ImportError: cannot import name generic
```

This last error shouldn't be happening at all because I've overriden the app in my project. But it's still reading the universally installed option. Django, however, runs just fine.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: If you've fixed review, then I would uninstall the old one in your site packages. If celery and django are importing different modules, it sounds like they have different python paths (try printing/logging `sys.path`) to check. If you post the content of core.forms, it might show why the import is failing.

Comment: Hm, that's crazy. Uninstalling `review` from site packages fixed everything. I realize now that in my `core/forms.py` I was importing review for something else. That's where it was failing, the other errors appear to be a false alarm. That said, the python path seemed correct so I'm not sure why it was calling that one.